# Replace non-html and replace it with correct syntax

Tags: javascript, html

I have a source program that delivers text with non html tags and incorrect syntax. 
for example:

```
the <H>quick</> brown fox.
the <U>quick</> brown fox.
<H><U>The</> quick brown fox.
<H><U>The</> quick </> brown fox.
```

The out come should be someting like:

the **quick** brown fox.

the *quick* brown fox.

***The*** quick brown fox.

***The*** **quick**  brown fox.

So the tags used are not html-valid, but also not closed as they should.
I'm struggling to get this working in javascript.

started with something like:

```
var s = document.getElementById('root').innerHTML;
s = s.replace("&lt;H&gt;", "<b>");  
s = s.replace("&lt;h&gt;", "<b>");    
s = s.replace("&lt;/&gt;","</b>");   
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = s;
```

root is the all containing div. The tags will appier in a div with class "label components", there will be multiple divs with class "label components" (and thus multiple times the incorrect tags on a page).

how can I best tackle this?

Comment: Regular expressions are not great at parsing valid markup, so I'd imagine even worse for invalid markup. I think you'll probably have to write a small parser...

Comment: If you decide to go that route, this tutorial seems pretty good: https://medium.com/@gajus/parsing-absolutely-anything-in-javascript-using-earley-algorithm-886edcc31e5e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easiest to write a small parser/processor that uses a stack to keep track of the tags that still need to be closed:

```js
const s1 = 'the <H>quick</> brown fox.';
const s2 = 'the <U>quick</> brown fox.';
const s3 = '<H><U>The</> quick brown fox.';
const s4 = '<H><U>The</> quick </> brown fox.';

const process = (s) => {
  const map = {'H': 'b', 'U': 'i'};
  const stack = [];
  
  return s.replace(/<([A-Z/])>/g, (_, t) => {
    if (map[t]) {
      stack.push(map[t]);
      return `<${map[t]}>`;
    } else {
      return `</${stack.pop()}>`;
    }
  });
};

console.log(process(s1));
console.log(process(s2));
console.log(process(s3));
console.log(process(s4));
```

Your third example still comes out to be invalid HTML, because of the fact that the number of opening and closing tags doesn't match. If that's more than just a mistake in your example, you'll be looking at a more complex solution, and would need to specify what the desired behavior is supposed to be.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion the best route in this case would be to open html document in editor like VS Code and use **find and replace tool**.
You should also use **HTMLHint exten**sion for VS Code to highlight all the problems in html document.

Comment: The source tool is providing the data. The solution should by dynamic. So doing a manual find/replace is not the solution.